# Angular 7 - Services and subscriptions

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to understand services and subscriptions in Angular 7. Posted on Udemy forums, but was told to ask here.

I am trying to understand how services and subscriptions work. This is my setup -

**users.service.ts**

```
getUser(emailAddress: string) {
  return this.getallUsers().allusers.find(u => u.emailaddress === emailAddress);
}

public userSelected = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

**users.component.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['.']" (click)="onUserSelected(user)"> {{ user.emailaddress }} </a>
```

**users.component.ts**

```
onUserSelected(user: User) {
  this.selectedUser = user;
  this.usersService.userSelected.emit(user.emailaddress);
}
```

When the user clicks on the link, `userSelected: string` is emitted. Then I setup the subscription in another component (on the same page),

```
export class UserMiniComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usersService.userSelected.subscribe(
      (email: string) => {
        this.user = this.usersService.getUser(email); // email is caught here correctly
        console.log("");
      }
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see from the image below, the subscription is triggered properly. However, not sure why the `user` and `usersService` variables are in `undefined` state, when inside the subscription block. Do you know why? Breaking my head trying to understand this. Please help!

I would like to set the `this.user` properly from within the subscription.

[image]

Comment: What is this.getAllUsers() inside the service

Comment: It returns all user objects from a json. This part works fine, that's why I didn't include it.

Comment: you are trying to access the `this` context inside the debugger, but because your code is probably transpiled to ES5, the `this` context is not there. (which is odd.. that's why im not writing an answer, because it should always have a `this`). However, I believe you can access it using `this_.user` or `_this.user`, can't remember

Comment: nice! `_this.user` worked. But this is working only in debug console of vscode. `_this` is not recognized in the code editor, nor in chrome debugger.

Comment: another point. you should not use the `EventEmitter` inside services. These should only be used for `@Output` decorators inside components/directives

Comment: ah, good to know. I will make this change. Just following what was shown in the course, but with my own example.

Comment: @PhaniAnne that's because `_this` is inside the transpiled code, the code that's actually running in the browser. The reason you cannot see it in the chrome debugger though, is because chrome uses the generated sourcemaps and can read from there. VsCode apparently does not load the sourcemaps inside the debugger.

Comment: Exactly what @PierreDuc stated, `@Output()` should not be used in services. You should consider using the example [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) that utilizes subjects to broadcast data.

Comment: @PierreDuc I changed it to emit a local variable in `users` component and transferred it to my other compnent using property binding. It's good now! Thanks again for your help and advice :)